# AWS Simple workflow notification technique

Tags: amazon-web-services, spring-boot, amazon-swf

I'm new to AWS SWF and my task is to give notification(thru email) when an activity fails during first attempt ONLY. I'm using `Settable<Boolean>` as my flag but the value is not reliable because the workflow is running async. Here's my code:

```
 final AsyncExecutor asyncExecutor = new AsyncRetryingExecutor(retryPolicy, workflowClock);
 final Settable<Boolean> notifyException = new Settable<>();

    new TryCatch() {
        @Override
        protected void doTry() throws Throwable {
            asyncExecutor.execute(() -> new TryCatch() {
                @Override
                protected void doTry() throws Throwable {
                    Promise<ActivityOne> activityOne = activityOneClient.performAction(activityOneRequest);
                }

                @Override
                protected void doCatch(Throwable e) throws Throwable {
                    if (!notifyException.isReady()) {
                        // PERFORM notification service here!!
                        notifyException.set(true);
                    } else {
                        // DO NOTHING. Notification is already sent the first time :)
                    }

                    throw e;
                }
            });
        }

        @Override
        protected void doCatch(Throwable e) throws Throwable {
            System.out.println("======");
            System.out.println("CATCH ALL!! " + e.getMessage());
            System.out.println("======");
        }
    };
```

The `notifyException` 's value is always changing even though I explicitly set its value to `true` inside `if statement`. The result of my code is it will perform more than 1 the `notification service`.

====UPDATE===

```
 final AsyncExecutor asyncExecutor = new AsyncRetryingExecutor(retryPolicy, workflowClock);
 final Settable<Boolean> notifyException = new Settable<>();

    new TryCatch() {
        @Override
        protected void doTry() throws Throwable {
            asyncExecutor.execute(() -> new TryCatch() {
                @Override
                protected void doTry() throws Throwable {
                    Promise<ActivityOne> activityOne = activityOneClient.performAction(activityOneRequest);
                }

                @Override
                protected void doCatch(Throwable e) throws Throwable {
                    if (!notifyException.isReady()) {
                        activityOneClient.notify();
                        notifyException.set(true);
                    }
                    throw e;
                }
            });
        }

        @Override
        protected void doCatch(Throwable e) throws Throwable {
            System.out.println("======");
            System.out.println("CATCH ALL!! " + e.getMessage());
            System.out.println("======");
        }
    };
```

When I re-throw the exception, the `activityOneClient.notify()` will only be executed on the last retry of `asyncExecutor`, so if I dont re-throw, the `activityOneClient.notify()` will be executed automatically. I just need to notify if an exception occur for the first time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the code looks okay-ish (haven't run it).

your problem is somewhere else. the way the flow framework works is that every time there is some work to do the workflow workers or the activity workers pick up the task, run it and report back the results. reporting back the results means that the result of the execution is captured in the workflow history.

whenever the history changes the decider (workflow) worker runs and makes a decision to what should happen next. under the covers the decider just replays all the history and makes all the decisions from the beginning of time. now, it the decisions match what's in the history the decider just goes on until it hits something new.

simple example. say you have a workflow that has 3 steps:

- activity1
- activity2 - depends on result of activity1
- activity3 - depends on result of activity2

[ keep in mind that multiply activities can run at the same time, and if there isn't a link between output of an activity and input into the other the flow framework will move ahead and schedule multiple things in parallel. keeping it simple so that you get the idea ]

at T0 when the workflow starts there is no history, the decider runs and activity1 is scheduled.

at T1 the activity1 workers pick up the task, execute it and report the result.

at T2 as a result of activity1 updating history the decider is scheduled and runs + it reads the history. it sees activity1 should run, it sees it in the history, it sees that it completed, it schedules activity2

at T3 the activity2 workers pick up the task, execute it and report the result.

at T4 as a result of activity2 updating history the decider is scheduled and runs + it reads the history. it sees activity1 should run, it sees it in the history, it sees that it completed. it now sees that activity2 should run, it sees it in the history, it sees that it's completed and move on to activity3. it schedules activity3.

and so on.

your problem is that the code in the decider that dictates the flow is **run every time  the decider runs** (every decision). so when the decider reaches that activity it will see that it has run and has thrown and exception and it will go though the code that sets the flag + sends the email.

when the exponential retries kick is, the flag will be set, but the code that sends the email will be run on every decision (the decider is basically stateless and the state is built based on the history).

what you could do in this particular case is to move the part that sends the email in its own activity. this way the decider will see it in the history and fast forward instead of running it each time.

Comment: Ok :) I got the idea. I forgot that deciders are stateless(thanks). Now, my problem is how can I know if the exception thrown was the first exception happened in that specific workflow. My client just need to be notified once when exception occur in activityOne and if activityOne throws again an error, notification service should NOT run.

Comment: what I would personally do is catch the exception in the activity and indicate that the activity was not successful via return code.

Comment: Well, `activityOne` is stateless too. How can I store or say that the next exception occurred doesn't need notification service.

Comment: When decider replays activity it is not executed multiple times as it knows from history that it already executed. So your code should work without modification. Just change "// PERFORM notification service here!!" comment with the notification activity invocation.

Comment: Hi Mircea. Thanks for your answer. I really do believe that this is working however there are times that the activity inside the doCatch() is not being executed even after I rebuild the application (I'm really sure it should be executed). Any idea?

Comment: can you provide a self contained sample of your app that shows this issue?

Comment: I just updated the question. I think I found the problem. When I re-throw the exception, the activity inside the doCatch() will only be executed on the last retry of asyncExecutor().

Comment: think that's the expected behavior. If you have activities that throw + have retries flow will not bubble them up unless all retries/timeouts are consumed.

Comment: Any idea how can I perform an activity in `doCatch()` for the first thrown exception only? So sorry, I'm too desperate now. :)

Answer (score 0):

To notify only the first exception thrown, what I did is:

```
@Override
    protected void doTry() throws Throwable {
        asyncExecutor.execute(() -> new TryCatchFinally() {

            Throwable throwable = null;
            @Override
            protected void doTry() throws Throwable {
                Promise<ActivityOne> activityOne = activityOneClient.performAction(activityOneRequest);
            }

            @Override
            protected void doCatch(Throwable e) throws Throwable {
                if (!notifyException.isReady()) {
                    activityOneClient.notify();
                    notifyException.set(true);
                }
                throwable = e;
            }

            @Override
            protected void doFinally() throws Throwable {
                if (throwable != null) {
                    throw throwable;
                }
            }
        });
    }
```